# I want to get a NRF24L01 transceiver to use as a switch to wake up a toy, but is it possible to use it without a separate controller attached?

Tags: rf, circuits, nrf24l01

To give more detail, the toy I'm trying to modify has a reset pin that I would like to tap remotely, as it goes to sleep after a few minutes and hitting that reset pin wakes it up. As such, while I do want to use RF because it's a pain to open the toy, I don't need to actually send any data other than a single 1 (HIGH) when I want to wake it up, and for battery reasons I was hoping it would be possible to do this without attaching the receiver to a RPi Zero or Arduino.

My plan was to figure out how to program the transmitter & receiver on my RPi Zero, and then attach one of the serial pins on the receiver directly to the reset pin, and then try to light up that specific serial pin from the transmitter attached to the RPi Zero. Would this work or is this a bad idea? And if so what pin should I connect it to? It seems like my options might be "CSN", "SCK", "MOSI", and "MISO".

I haven't actually bought an NRF24L01 yet because I wanted to figure out if it would work first, those pin names were what I found on the datasheet for it.

Comment: Since I have the experience and tools laying about, I'd just go out and buy a SOT-23-6 MCU (PIC10LF, likely), and program it up. Wouldn't take much. The NRF24L01, though, does require some initialization and that really needs an MCU. So kind of stuck there. I just wouldn't overdo it with some giant board. You only need the one IC and it's very tiny. Just solder it to the back of the NRF24L01.

Comment: @jonk thank you for the response, when you say it needs initialization, it's not a 1 time thing I could do attached to a RPI zero and then DC it? It'd have to be something permanently attached to it?

Comment: I can't say as I've not read the details about that unit. In general, when a device like that "powers up" (gets access to a supply voltage) it pre-initializes itself into some "mode." That mode may not be the one you want (probably isn't a mode you want, if I were guessing.) Having a tiny MCU there allows you to MAKE DARNED SURE that the initialization gets done the way you want and also provides you with the simple pin you want, too. I don't think pre-programming with an RPI gets you there unless this device also includes some non-volatile storage for your purposes. Which I doubt.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for the help! Looks like I've gotta look into programming microcontrollers now haha. Thank you again!

Comment: The PIC10 family is very very cheap. The programmers are cheap. The MPLAB software is free. And the I/O devices are perhaps the least complicated ones to understand, too. (By comparison, the PIC10 I/O initialization code is just a few lines of assembly whereas the initialization code for a 32-bit ARM is hundreds if not thousands of such lines, taking into account chipset errata and more.) Sure, you do still have to actually READ PIC10 stuff to get it right. But you can just focus on the parts that matter. The serial coms to the device will be the harder parts.

Comment: use a cheap transmitter module with a separate receiver module ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=433+mhz+radio+module&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images